# Angular and Jade unexpected token error

Tags: angularjs, pug

New to Jade, trying to figure it out. I keep getting a wonky error saying:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular-resource.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular-route.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
app.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I'm wondering if there's an issue grabbing my files/scripts? In the scripts.jade file, it looks like this:

```
script(type="text/javascript", src="multivision/vendor/jquery/jquery.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="multivision/vendor/angular/angular.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="multivision/vendor/angular-   resource/angular-resource.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="multivision/vendor/angular- route/angular-route.js")
script(type="text/javascript", src="multivision/app/app.js")
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you getting 404 for each *.js files? Chrome-dev-tools Network tab, and also what is your static folder?

Comment: Problem resolved by changing pathway to the files, new errors came up after:

    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
    ReferenceError: when is not defined